# How to use std::conditional such that all options have a check / no option is the default

Tags: c++, c++14

`std::conditional_t` can be nested perpetually:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>

enum class data_types { single_bytes, four_byte_integrals, four_byte_floats };
    
template<data_types expected_type>
std::conditional_t<expected_type == data_types::single_bytes,        uint8_t,
std::conditional_t<expected_type == data_types::four_byte_integrals, int32_t,
                                                                     float>>
parse(const uint8_t * rawBytes)
{
    using return_t = std::conditional_t<expected_type == data_types::single_bytes,        uint8_t,
                     std::conditional_t<expected_type == data_types::four_byte_integrals, int32_t,
                                                                                          float>>;
    constexpr auto length = sizeof(return_t);
    return_t result;
    std::memcpy(&result, rawBytes, length);
    return result;
}
```

However, this leaves the last option as the default case, if all conditions fail. This may be undesirable.

`std::enable_if` exists to prevent template instantiation if a condition is not fulfilled:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>

enum class data_types { single_bytes, four_byte_integrals, four_byte_floats };

template<data_types expected_type>
std::enable_if_t<expected_type == data_types::four_byte_floats , float>
parse(const uint8_t * rawBytes)
{
    float result;
    constexpr auto length = sizeof(float);
    std::memcpy(&result, rawBytes, length);
    return result;
}
```

But nesting `std::enable_if` into `std::conditional` fails **always**, even if an earlier branch would suffice (`std::conditional` does not short-circuit):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>

enum class data_types { single_bytes, four_byte_integrals, four_byte_floats };
    
template<data_types expected_type>
std::conditional_t<expected_type == data_types::single_bytes,        uint8_t,
std::conditional_t<expected_type == data_types::four_byte_integrals, int32_t,
std::enable_if_t<expected_type == data_types::four_byte_floats,      float>>>
parse(const uint8_t * rawBytes)
{
    using return_t = std::conditional_t<expected_type == data_types::single_bytes,        uint8_t,
                     std::conditional_t<expected_type == data_types::four_byte_integrals, int32_t,
                     std::enable_if_t<expected_type == data_types::four_byte_floats,      float>>>;
    constexpr auto length = sizeof(return_t);
    return_t result;
    std::memcpy(&result, rawBytes, length);
    return result;
}
```

emits "error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, float>'" for e.g. this use:

```
int main()
{
  uint8_t rawBytes[]{ 1u, 2u, 3u, 4u };
  auto x{ parse<data_types::single_bytes>(rawBytes) };
}
```

How can we define a dependent type that will fail if no option is valid, but *only* if no option is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might delay instantiation with `std::type_identity` and use extra `::type` std::conditional_t<>::type

```
using type =
    typename std::conditional_t<
      expected_type == data_types::single_bytes, std::type_identity<uint8_t>,
      std::conditional_t<expected_type == data_types::four_byte_integrals, std::type_identity<int32_t>,
      std::enable_if<expected_type == data_types::four_byte_floats, float>>

//               ^^^^ no _t here
      >::type; // extra `::type` here, for the type inside conditional_t
```

Comment: Accepting this one, as it is the closest to "the naive approach" and also most concise for my current use case, where I do not plan to reuse the type anywhere else.

Answer (score 5):

Use helper classes to map enum values to types, and do not provide member type aliases when the enum value is invalid

```
enum class data_types { single_bytes, four_byte_integrals, four_byte_floats };
template<data_types expected_type>
struct enum_to_type { };
template<>
struct enum_to_type<data_types::single_bytes>        { using type = uint8_t; };
template<>
struct enum_to_type<data_types::four_byte_integrals> { using type = int32_t; };
template<>
struct enum_to_type<data_types::four_byte_floats>    { using type = float; };
```

and then use it like this

```
template<data_types expected_type>
typename enum_to_type<expected_type>::type
parse(const uint8_t * rawBytes)
{
  using return_t = typename enum_to_type<expected_type>::type;
  // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aWhxo8s9x)

Comment: Upvoted: This looks a bit verbose, but it lends itself well to pretty formatting and thence scales well with greater variation. It is also the better solution for the case, that one were to reuse the so-defined type elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the return type into its own alias template, with `void` as default, and then use that with `std::enable_if`:

```
template<data_types expected_type>
using parse_return_t = std::conditional_t<
    expected_type == data_types::single_bytes, uint8_t,
    std::conditional_t<
        expected_type == data_types::four_byte_integrals, int32_t,
        std::conditional_t<
            expected_type == data_types::four_byte_floats, float, void
        >
    >
>;

template<data_types expected_type>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<parse_return_t<expected_type>, void>, parse_return_t<expected_type>>
parse(const uint8_t * rawBytes)
{
    constexpr auto length = sizeof(parse_return_t<expected_type>);
    parse_return_t<expected_type> result;
    std::memcpy(&result, rawBytes, length);
    return result;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f81h384zG)

If you don't want `void` as default, you can just create another type, like `struct InvalidType {};`.

Answer (score 0):

Template tooling from type_traits is useful, but there are some cases where it is more handy to Do It Yourself. I think this is your case:

```cpp
enum class data_types { single_bytes, four_byte_integrals, four_byte_floats };

template<data_types expected_type>
struct type_for_parsing;

template<>
struct type_for_parsing<data_types::single_bytes>
{
    using type = uint8_t;
};

template<>
struct type_for_parsing<data_types::four_byte_integrals>
{
    using type = int32_t;
};

template<>
struct type_for_parsing<data_types::four_byte_floats>
{
    using type = float;
};

template<data_types expected_type>
using type_for_parsing_t = typename type_for_parsing<expected_type>::type;

template<data_types expected_type>
type_for_parsing_t<expected_type> parse(const uint8_t * rawBytes);
```

Comment: Same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76681660/21285803)

Comment: Didn't see it when I was writing that.